# How should "7 $\log_{10}$" be interpreted?

Tags: notation, logarithms

A [cookery related article](http://www.fsis.usda.gov/OPPDE/rdad/FSISNotices/RTE_Poultry_Tables.pdf) I want to refer to mentions a  *"7 log<sub>10</sub> relative reduction of salmonella"*. A few related sources suggest this evaluates to 10,000,000, although I would have imagined that 10<sup>7</sup> is the usual way of expressing this.

I initially thought that I should interpret this as log<sub>10</sub>(7) but that doesn't seem right given that an 85% reduction in salmonella can hardly be considered safe.

If the first interpretation is correct, could someone tell me why it might have been expressed this way, rather than as a power of 10?

Comment: could this perhaps be better asked on [Seasoned Advice/Cooking.SE](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this pag](http://www.ciriscience.org/a_107-What_is_Log_Reduction)e a 7 log reduction is a reduction in number of microorganisms by 10000000-fold (so $10^7$). It seems like this is something that is often used in food science.

So I guess that the basic idea is that if you draw the relationship between cooking time needed for a certain reduction in organisms and the time, then you get a logarithmic relationship, so  maybe that is why they chose to use the log notation to emphasize this fact.

There is more about this log-reduction [here](http://www.freedrinkingwater.com/water_health/health2/47-08-log-removal-explanation-biological-contaminants.htm) or [here](http://www.healthyfacilitiesinstitute.com/a_50-Basics_of_Log_Reduction).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that:

$$ \log_{10} (10,000,000)=7$$

So instead of writing the 1 followed by 7 zeros, that (strange) notation ($7\log_{10}$) might have been used instead. Of course there are other more common notations such as the power and the E.